# Get list of selected elements from dropdown menu to django view

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

I am new to UI design. My objective is to select the multiple items from a dropdown menu and send the selected to a django view.
I wrote the entire code and able to select multiple fields using bootstrap+chosen but after submitting I am getting this error:

"GET /static/app/css/chosen-sprite.png HTTP/1.1" 304

After searching in the web, I found out that this file is required as chosen saves the selected items in this file. I have this file in my css folder(downloaded from net) but dont know what I am doing wrong.

Below is my code and right now I am printing the selected items in the same html page. Please help me :(

project_select.html

```
{% block body %}
    <p><br/></p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Select projects:</h3>
                <form id="selectProject" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'displayselectedprojects' %}">
                    <select form="selectProject" data-placeholder="Choose projects" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4" name="params[]">
                        {% for project in project_names %}
                            <option> {{ project.projectname }} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <h3><br></h3>
                <input type="button" value="Submit" style="padding: 4px 28px;border-radius: 4px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Here is selection:</p>

    <p>{{ title}} <br />
       {{ projectList }}</p>

    <script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'displayselectedprojects/', views.displayselectedprojects, name='displayselectedprojects'),
```

views.py

```
def displayselectedprojects(request):

    selected_packages = request.GET.getlist('params[]')
    print('selected packages: %s' % selected_packages)

    context = {
        'title': 'i reached here',
        'projectList': selected_packages,
    }

    return render(request, 'app/project_select.html', context)
```

Comment: What error are you getting and can you share the model you want to save too?

Comment: I am getting this "GET /static/app/css/chosen-sprite.png HTTP/1.1" 304, and i dont have any model for saving this, these will be parameters for retrieving data from a model and not storing these.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the issue, not sure its the actual solution or a workaround but I replaced all the references of the file 'chosen-sprite.png' with its cdn: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen-sprite.png' and its working now.